# How to check if a file exists without error?

Tags: php, file

I like to do this:

```
if (file_exists( "path/a/b/c/file.txt" )) {
   fopen("path/a/b/c/file.txt");  ----------> ERROR
   do_this_if_file_exists();

}
else {
   do_this_if_not_exists();
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
fopen(path/a/b/c/file.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What I'm doing wrong with file_exists?

In addition, when I call file exists with a path like: `file_exists( "file.txt" )`, that works well. I think the problem is the path (path/a/b/c/), but how to verify that without create the path first.

Thanks.

Comment: you seem to answer your own question, use the correct path

Comment: Can you show an exact example of a path that you are passing to `file_exists()` and that is wrongly returning true? Are you 100% sure it's 100% the same path as you are using in your function?

Comment: It will be better if you show the real code, as in this one there won't be any problems

Answer (score 1):

It is not a proper way to hide errors with @. All errors should be correctly handled. In other case debugging will be a pain.

Also, for the future you may use is_readable() function to make sure if the file is not only exists but also is readable, e.g. you have enough permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include error checking with [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

```
if (file_exists( "path/a/b/c/file.txt" )) 
{
   $fh=fopen("path/a/b/c/file.txt","r"); #or whatever mode you want...
   if($fh!==false)
   {
      do_this_if_file_exists_and_can_be_opened();
   }
   else
   {
      die("Couldn't open the file.  Sorry!\n");
   }
}
else {
   do_this_if_not_exists();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if given file exists and if it is realy a file:

```
if (file_exists( "path/a/b/c/file.txt" ) && is_file("path/a/b/c/file.txt")) {
    $file_handler = @fopen("path/a/b/c/file.txt", MODE_IS_NOT_OPTIONAL)
    if($file_handler !== false){
        do_things_with_file_handler();
    } else {
        throw_some_error();
    }
}
else {
    do_this_if_not_exists();
}
```

Function `file_exists()` also can check if given directory exists and that shluod help You.

`mode` parameter in `fopen` function isn't optional as @Jack Maney pointed out. You have to use one of the mode possible values, [full list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
fopen("path/a/b/c/file.txt");
```

Not only are you not assigning the return value to anything, but [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) takes a required 2nd argument that you are not using.

Answer (score -3):

You may turn off the error reporting by adding this line at the top of your php page

error_reporting(0);

Comment: "Boy, those smoke detectors sure were annoying before I took the batteries out!  Say, do you smell something burning?"